# How to use Telerik grid with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I created a simple mvc 5 web application using database first approach. 
I followed example as shown in this website. 
https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database. We purchased the Telerik ASP.NET MVC Components. Can anyone guide me on how can I use the GRID component to connect to database table and display results in GRID. I really need detail steps like example above

Thanks You.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Telerik demos:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/index

They have tons of recipes for doing just about everything you could want.

Comment: Yes I looked at them. Sadly none of them have step by step. For beginners it's really very difficult. I already have a MVC project based on example I gave. Now I have to use their Grid. I don't see any example step by step that shows how to use to an existing project.